# Need help parsing a value into a Supabase fetch data call

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, supabase

I am trying to parse a value from an HTML page:

```
<td><a href="/Event?id=<%=event.id%>" title="event"><%=event.event_name%></a></td>
```

to a javascript function using a Supabase as my database:

```
app.get('/Event', async (req, res) => {
    let { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('events')
    .select('*')
    .eq('id', ?)  //issue is here

    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return
    }

    res.render('Event', { "event": data});
  });
```

Here are the Supabase docs: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/eq

The error I get when running the code is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
app.get('/Event', async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.query.id;

    let { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('events')
    .select('*')
    .eq('id', id)  //fixed

    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return
    }

    res.render('Event', { "event": data});
  });
```